# Long Polling in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, long-polling

I need to do API calls to display the progress of something.

I have created a service which does this every 1.5 seconds

**Main Component**

```
private getProgress() {
        this.progressService.getExportProgress(this.type, this.details.RequestID);
    }
```

**Services.ts**

```
public getExportProgress(type: string, requestId: string) {
    Observable.interval(1500)
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint + "Definition/" + type + "/Progress/" + requestId))
        .map((data) => data.json().Data)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            if (!data.InProgress)
                //Stop doing this api call
        },
        error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

The call works, but it keeps going. I want to stop doing the API call when the progress is finished (`if (!data.InProgress`) but I'm stuck on this.

How can I correctly unsubscribe from this observable when `if (!data.InProgress)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the `takeWhile` operator.

Here is the documentation:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile

> Emits values emitted by the source Observable so long as each value
>   satisfies the given predicate, and then completes as soon as this
>   predicate is not satisfied.

Here is a generic example:
https://rxviz.com/v/yOE6Z5JA

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(100)
  .takeWhile(x => x < 10)
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

Here is an example with your code:

```
public getExportProgress(type: string, requestId: string) {
    Observable.interval(1500)
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint + "Definition/" + type + "/Progress/" + requestId))
        .map((data) => data.json().Data)
        .takeWhile((data) => data.InProgress)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            ...
        },
        error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this by putting the service call in a variable, and unsubscribing from that variable when I'm done.

Here's the result:

```
public getExportProgress(type: string, requestId: string): any {
    let progress = Observable.interval(1500)
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint + "Definition/" + type + "/Progress/" + requestId))
        .map((data) => data.json().Data)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {              
            if (!data.InProgress) {
                this.toastyCommunicationService.addSuccesResponseToast("done");
                progress.unsubscribe();
            }            
        },
        error => this.handleError(error));
}
```