# Polling an http service with dependencies

Tags: angular, observable

So, I've followed the answer from this question: [Long Polling in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728922/long-polling-in-angular-4)
but am still having problems.

The endpoint that I need to call and poll requires data from a call to another endpoint. So what I have is the following:

```
return this.postJob(ids)
    .flatMap(postRes => {
        return Observable
            .interval(250)
            .switchMap(() => { 
                console.log("POSTRES: " + JSON.stringify(postRes, null, 2); 
                return this.getJob(postRes.id);
            })
            .map(getRes => getRes)
            .takeWhile(getRes => {
                console.log("GETRES: " + JSON.stringify(getRes, null, 2); 
                return getRes.statusCode !== Constants.COMPLETE;
            })
            .catch(SharedHttpMethods.handleError);
    });
```

And I call that with:

```
processJob(ids).subscribe(jobRes => { 
    console.log("downloadSelected: ", JSON.stringify(jobRes, null, 2)); 
    // act on the completed response 
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the postJobs service is called over and over again. `.takeWhile` never kills the subscription.  I am supposing that the flatMap may have something to do with that, but I am uncertain.

Any suggestions on what I need to do to fix this issue?

**Notes:**
postJob and getJob returns the same json object model. However, getJob depends on the id returned from the postJobs call.

When I run my current code, I can see "QUEUED", "PROCESSING", and finally "COMPLETED". But they all happen multiple times.

Okay... it turns out I didn't look at my response closely enough.

** UPDATE with moderate successes **
Constants.COMPLETE = "COMPLETE"

The statusCode is giving me "COMPLETED".

Once I worked that out, `getRes.statusCode !== Constants.COMPLETED`, everything was working properly.

But I've run into a new problem. Once the `.takeWhile` gets a false statement, it stops the Observable. But it doesn't pass the final COMPLETED object back.

So, I get

```
GETRES: ... QUEUED
downloadSelected: ... QUEUED
GETRES: ... COMPLETED
```

but I do not get `downloadSelected: ... COMPLETED`.
What am I missing

**Output:**

```
"POSTJOB":  {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "QUEUED",
}
"GETJOB":  {
 "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "QUEUED",
}
"downloadSelected": {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "QUEUED",
}
"POSTJOB":  {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "QUEUED",
}
"GETJOB":  {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "PROCESSING",
}
"downloadSelected": {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "PROCESSING",
}
"POSTJOB":  {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "QUEUED",
}
"GETJOB":  {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44"
    },
    "zip": {
      "href": "linkToZipFile"
    }
  },
  "id": 44,
  "statusCode": "COMPLETED",
}
```

Comment: Is `flatMap` working as you want it to work?

Comment: As far as I can tell. I've got a couple of console loggers in the code I didn't repeat above and it shows me that both `postJob` and `getJob` calls are working and returning the correct data. The first response shows `{ id: 44, _links: { self: { href: "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44" } }, statusCode: "QUEUED" }` and some moment later gives me: `{ id: 44, _links: { self: { href: "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jobs/44" }, zip: { href: "linkToZipFile"} }, statusCode: "COMPLETED" }`

Comment: My guess is that your takeWhile is only completing the outer observable. Try also adding it to the inner observable within your switchMap `return this.getJob(postRes.id).takeWhile(...)`

Comment: After reading more about takeWhile, my above comment doesnt make sense :/ you said `.takeWhile never kills the subscription`. Do you mean you get 2 emits that are `COMPLETED`? or the observable sequence never stops and runs indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... it turns out I didn't look at my response closely enough.

Constants.COMPLETE = "COMPLETE"

The statusCode is giving me "COMPLETED".

Once I worked that out, `getRes.statusCode !== Constants.COMPLETED`, everything was working properly.

For those who are looking for an answer on how to do multiple calls while utilizing `.takeWhile`, the answer is in the question. I needed the first object returned when statusCode==COMPLETED, but not anything beyond that first one.  `.takeWhile` returns everything before COMPLETED.  `.skipWhile` returns everything from the first COMPLETED and after. `.take(1)` limits the `.skipWhile` to just one call.

The answer I needed is the following.  It utilizes `.skipWhile` and `.take`.

```
return this.postJob(ids)
    .flatMap(postRes => {
        return Observable
            .interval(250)
            .switchMap(() => { 
                console.log("POSTRES: " + JSON.stringify(postRes, null, 2); 
                return this.getJob(postRes.id);
            })
            .map(getRes => getRes)
            .skipWhile(getRes => {
                console.log("GETRES: " + JSON.stringify(getRes, null, 2); 
                return getRes.statusCode !== Constants.COMPLETE;
            })
            .take(1)
            .catch(SharedHttpMethods.handleError);
    });
```